# React: Props destructuring and memory usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Does using destructuring assignments affect memory usage/performance if the declared constants **are only used once**? In other languages (Java, C, etc), **it's best not to declare a variable if it's only used once, as it allocates unnecessary memory**. Is this also true with ES6 JS?

I have 2 examples of what I'm talking about. The first uses destructuring assignments and calls each constant just once. The second calls this.props each time it is used and does not declare them in advance. Which one uses less memory? Our code base is pretty evenly split between the 2, but I'm curious as to which way is better for scale.

with destructuring assignment for single-reference variables:

```
render(){
   const {
      a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
   } = this.props;
   return(
      <div>
         <div id={a}>some text relevant to a</div>
         <div id={b}>some text relevant to b</div>
         <div id={c}>some text relevant to c</div>
         <div id={d}>some text relevant to d</div>
         <div id={e}>some text relevant to e</div>
         <div id={f}>some text relevant to f</div>
         <div id={g}>some text relevant to g</div>
         <div id={h}>some text relevant to h</div>
         <div id={i}>some text relevant to i</div>
      </div>
   );
}
```

without declaring constants for single-reference variables:

```
render(){
   return(
      <div>
         <div id={this.props.a}>some text relevant to a</div>
         <div id={this.props.b}>some text relevant to b</div>
         <div id={this.props.c}>some text relevant to c</div>
         <div id={this.props.d}>some text relevant to d</div>
         <div id={this.props.e}>some text relevant to e</div>
         <div id={this.props.f}>some text relevant to f</div>
         <div id={this.props.g}>some text relevant to g</div>
         <div id={this.props.h}>some text relevant to h</div>
         <div id={this.props.i}>some text relevant to i</div>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: The general rule with JS is unless you've noticed a problem specifically, don't worry about it. All common engines are JITs these days so it's entirely possible that those variables will be entirely optimized out. At the end of the day this question isn't answerable because it depends on whatever optimizations the JIT happens to do, which could even vary within the same engine depending on how the code is used.

Comment: @loganfsmyth where we can find more details of the JIT about props destructuring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue with the first answer. When doing

```
const {
      a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
} = this.props;
```

you allocate memory for these variables. Although you'll need some extra memory, it wont be significant because objects (including arrays, functions etc) will be defined as references/pointers.

Comment: In most scenarios the performance difference is negligible.  I found myself here because I have a scenario where I have a loop over hundreds or even thousands of iteration, each one destructuring once or two variables.  For my case, optimization is crucial.  Would the different be noticeable at that scale?